NAS not connecting to network
I set up a NAS with OpenMediaVault. When configuring the network during the out-of-box experience, I can connect to my main network and I get the comfirmation that the connection has been established. I successfully load into the shell and log in as root. 
I type the if config command to try to get the local ip and I get an error saying ifconfig: command not found. I try to install the networking tools with sudo apt install net-tools and I get an error saying that I cannot fetch the required packets. I also can't ping my own network or any sites like when I try to ping google.com I encounter an error saying: Name or service not known. When I type ip addr show I see that my network interface didn't get an asigned local ip. I also notice, that when I'm loading into the bash I get an error: saying Unable to load network inteface.
Here's what I've tried:

Reinstalling OMV on the machine
Manually changing the /etc/network/interfaces file
Connecting to the guest network that we have
Manually bringing down the interface with ip link set down and then up with ip link set up
Changed the router DHCP configuration from 0.0.0.0 to Primary: 8.8.8.8 and Secondary: 8.8.8.4
Restarting the networking with systemctl restart networking

I have been dealing with this problem for a week now, and I can't seem figure out the solution.
